# Ordered Set with MyBatis

Tags: java, sql-order-by, set, mybatis

What is the correct way to define collection implementation using MyBatis. Consider example below. I want `LinkedHashSet` to be returned from mapping. Where should I specify `Set` implementation if I don't want to have `LinkedHashSet` hardcoded in mapping interface.

Mapping fragment :

```
<select id="selectAll" resultType="Language">
    SELECT 
        <include refid="languageColumns"/>
    FROM language
    ORDER BY ord
</select>
```

Mapping interface :

```
public interface LanguageDAO {

    public Set<Language> selectAll();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MyBatis converts the result to the return type of your method.

If you use a LinkedHashSet, it will create a LinkedHashSet. But if you specify a generic interface it will use a default implementation. In the case of Set I think it is a HashSet.

You can control that behaviour replacing the default ObjectFactory by your own one. Have a look at MyBatis DefaultObjectFactory.

Comment: You point me in right direction. Anyway for someone with this problem you should use `SortedSet` interface as result instead of `Set` if you want it sorted. All this happens in `DefaultObjectFactory` as Diego mentioned.